# Selenium Type library not showing in Excel (Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, selenium, pip

I installed Selenium via pip and I've installed the appropriate Chrome Driver too and have been able to webscrape successfully.

I then realised you could execute Selenium from VBA and so I tried doing the following:

```
Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

driver.Start "chrome", "www.google.co.uk"
driver.Open "/"


End Sub
```

I can see it didn't work as I need the Selenium Wrapper, So I've installed that via pip too.

However, I still can't find the option under Tools --> References for Selenium Type Library as stated in many tutorials. This usually allow VBA to execute the code..

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I don't think seleniumbasic is supported with mac. It is NET framework based.

Comment: ah ok! That makes sense then. Is there no other workaround for Mac OS? @QHarr

Comment: Use python and selenium? You might even be able to do that from Excel via add-in or COM.